# Expectation of a function of two variables, not with respect to the joint distribution

Tags: notation, expectation

I am confused by the following expectation which appears within equation (1) of the following paper http://statweb.stanford.edu/~jhf/ftp/trebst.pdf:

$E_{X}[E_{Y}[L(Y,F(X))]|X]$

I am confused by the inner expectation, which is a expectation of $L(Y,F(X))$ with respect to Y.  The result would also be $E_{X}[·|X]$ which doesn't make sense to me, since it would be the expectation with respect to the distribution of X, while conditioning on X.

Comment: My guess is that they meant $E_X[E_Y[L(Y,F(X)) \mid X]]$, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @user2943324 In that case, what is the outer expectation with respect to?  Is it an expectation of a constant, namely $g(x)$ with respect to X?  Also, should $E_{Y}[f(Y,x)]$ be respect to the conditional distribution $Y|X$ instead of the marginal distribution of $Y$?

Comment: Someone pointed out that there are a number of mis-matched parenthesis in the paper, and based on the 2nd equation in section 2, the author likely meant: $E_{X}[E_{Y}[L(Y,F(X))|X]]$.  Does anyone disagree with this?  This makes sense to me because by conditioning $L(Y,F(X))$ on $X$, the inner expectation can be taken over the distribution of $Y$, not $Y|X$.  The outer expectation would still be the expectation of the function evaluated at a given value $x$, but I think that this redundancy is intentional to help make the point that this is optimization over the function space.